# remove all tags from html text except specified in the list

Tags: regex

I need a RegularExpress that can remove all tags from text except specificed
like `br, strong, p, h1`

```
<^(br|strong|p|h1)(^>)*>.*</$1>
```

Comment: A regex won't do this job well.  You should use the appropriate HTML parser for your language.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: or `<? strip_tags($html,"<br><strong><p><h1>"); ?>`

Comment: What language are you using? RegExp flavor is critical for this question. Also, html parser shall be more proper for such tasks

Comment: can you add a sample text for us to practice on ?